# TypeError: Connect() takes exactly one argument

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm creating an extremely simple python script designed to open a TCP socket and send some JSON data. (I'm new to python)

I'm recieving an error below when I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "JSONTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    s.connect('10.12.0.30', 6634)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: connect() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

My script is below:

```
#Imports
import socket
import json
import time

data = "{\"method\": \"echo\",\"id\": \"echo\",\"params\": []}"

#Create socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Establish TCP session via IP address and port specified
s.connect('10.12.0.30', 6634)

#Send JSON to socket
s.send(json.dumps(data))

#Wait for response and print to console
result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
#print str(result)

#Exit
s.close()
```

I've checked the documentation on the socket library and connect() lists only a single argument, namely the destination IP address desired. So, my question is, how can I do the above, where I'm also specifying my TCP port, if the connect() method won't allow me to input it there?

I'm also open to input on better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Host and port must be a tuple.

```
s.connect(('10.12.0.30', 6634))
```

See the second part of the example in the [Python Socket documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example).

Answer (score 4):

You must call `connect` with one argument: a tuple with the host and the port:

```
s.connect(('10.12.0.30',6677))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution using socket.getaddrinfo:

```
ainfo = socket.getaddrinfo("10.12.0.30",6677)
s.connect(ainfo[0][4])
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check the version of the python because socket.connect(.....) takes tuple after version 2.0 and later, please follow the python documentation for that version here is the snip of the [documentation for python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect):

> **socket.connect(address)**
>
> Connect to a remote socket at address. (The format of address depends
> on the address family — see above.)
>
> *Note This method has historically accepted a pair of parameters for
> AF_INET addresses instead of only a tuple. This was never intentional
> and is no longer available in Python 2.0 and later.*